# Is there anyway to pass response of a HTTP sampler to request as another sampler in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing

I am testing rest API using Jmeter. In one scenario need to pass complete response of a http sampler to, another http sampler as a request  dynamically. Any suggestions how to achieve this in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which response data you want to capture
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `response`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the extracted value as `${response}` where required.

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `()` - grouping
- `(?s)` - single line modifier
- `^` - line start
- `.` - wild card character
- `*` - repetition

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all response using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with regex accepting all characters

In next JMeter 5.2 version you will able to do it using [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) by keeping [Left and Right Boundary empty](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63775)